# Continuously watch for a condition to be true without render in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

In my react project, I have a requirement where I have to check for a condition continuously and call a function as soon as the condition becomes true.

The condition looks like this:

```
var El = document.activeElement;
if(document.getElementById('myInputField').getAttribute('aria-invalid') === 'true'
   && !(document.getElementById('myInputField') === El) {

       // function call

}
```

How can this be achieved in ReactJs?

I'm okay to use jquery/javascript too.

Additional details:
I'm using an Input field from an external project. The input field checks the provided input and alter it's own `aria-invalid` attribute.
If the user submits the form with invalid input, I want to check if `aria-invalid` is true and focus is not on input field.

Comment: Its a bad idea to mix react and JS dom manipulation. If you could elaborate on what you are trying to achieve, we might be able to provide you a better solution

Comment: In fact, if you're working in React there is almost never a reason to access the DOM directly: the DOM is just your UI rendering layer, you shouldn't need to reach into it: your component state should already effect the correct DOM.

Comment: I have added an answer below but please read the React docs before posting any further questions regarding the library. They are fantastic and it will make you life a lot simpler than trying to learn React in a piecemeal fashion through stackoverflow questions.

Comment: Question. So your input is from external project but is it a rendered as a part of your project? Since you have a `submit form` event, you do not need a continuous check. In worst case scenario where input is not rendered in your app but is a part of page, add a listener on a HOC/ view component and validate it then

Answer (score 1):

The example below shows the correct and incorrect way to manipulate the DOM (in the context of React):

```js
// -> Imports
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

// -> Element Ids
const subHeading = "sub-heading";

// -> DOM Manipulator
// -> Don't do this, opt for conditional style instead
// -> Check h1 element for example
function sideEffect() {
  document.getElementById(subHeading).style.color = "red";
}

// -> Time Constant
const fiveSeconds = 5000;

export default function App() {
  // -> State
  const [readCond, writeCond] = useState(false);
  // -> Side Effects
  // -> Change readCond to true after five second pause
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => writeCond(true), fiveSeconds);
  }, []);
  // -> Trigger DOM manipulation when readCond is true
  useEffect(() => {
    if (readCond) sideEffect();
  }, [readCond]);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 style={{ color: readCond ? "red" : "black" }}>React Way - Good</h1>
      <h2 id={subHeading}>DOM Way - Bad</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-buck-n6527?file=/src/App.js:0-612)

Comment: There is an issue here. If `subHeading` is mutated from outside react, it will not invoke a re-render and your condition will not be validated. Like if I do `setTimeout(() => subHeading.style.color='black', 10000)`, and not call `writeCond`, your code will not work

Comment: @Rajesh what on earth are you on about? See "The example below shows the correct and **incorrect way** to manipulate the DOM", "**Don't do this**, opt for conditional style instead", "React Way - Good / **DOM Way - Bad** ". I could not have made it clearer that DOM manipulation was a bad idea...